# Getting Assertion Failed error when debugging Lua script

Tags: lua, zerobrane, luabridge

I have the following simple script, where I first require the lib which I have implemented on the C++ side. The latter has a MyData class defined with an API method GetNumPoints that returns the size of the data points stored in the class (the first input arg in the constructor, and the second arg is the number of points).

In the below Lua script if I have the SomeMethod() call commented out then it runs through and the output is "***userdata (2)***". But as soon as I remove the comments and run even the empty method in the script then I get the error seen in the attached image. Any idea what's happening here?

```
require "SciApiLuaExtLib"

local myData = MyData({0.1, 0.2}, 2)
print(type(myData) .. " (" .. myData:GetNumPoints() .. ")")

function SomeMethod()
end

--SomeMethod()
```

By the way on line 127 of the namespace.h file (as seen in the attached image) of the Lua Bridge there is the following C++ line:

`assert (lua_isuserdata (L, 1));               // warn on security bypass`

I use ZeroBrane for debugging (if that helps anyhow).

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that adding the function call *after* the line it fails on changes the behavior? I'd find this very strange. In any case, the assert clearly indicates that the value that is at the top of the stack is *not* userdata, so something corrupts the stack. Can you split the print statement and print the *type* separately from GetNumPoints call, so we can see what the type is when it fails (and not just when it succeeds).

Comment: Something is really weird. It turns out if I execute the script in ZeroBrane using the two green right arrow button (F6) then it runs without any issues, but if I run in debug mode using the one green arrow button (F5) then it fails with the abovementioned error.

Comment: You'd still need `type(myData)` printed to see what the value is when it fails. It does look like some sort of stack corruption, but I don't have any explanation for how the code that you're adding *after* the error can influence it.

Comment: The printout for type(myData) right after the light of assignment is "userdata".